# How do I get my input prompt to show up without pressing Enter before it's visible?

Tags: python, sockets, input

I am working with python sockets. Everything seems to be working fine, except for SOME reason, any time I receive from the server, my prompts stall until I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
# Sending a boolean from the server.
user_exists = serv_sock.recv(buffer).decode()

if user_exists:
    print('user exists so...')
    print('I can see this line, no problem. But not the next until enter is pressed')
    confirm = input('-=- Send file: (Y/N)')
```

Putting '\n' in the string doesn't work, it just prints an empty line. Is there a reason this is happening? Is there a way I can programmatically insert an <kbd>Enter</kbd> press?

Comment: I don't know why you are seeing that, but you could just print the prompt with a print function, and use an empty string as the input function argument.

Comment: The prompt still doesn't show OR accept input until after the print. Imagine if you just shifted my code up a line, it would be what you say, and still broken.

Answer (score 1):

To explain what I was saying in my comment, could you not rewrite it as:

```
# Sending a boolean from the server.
user_exists = serv_sock.recv(buffer).decode()

if user_exists:
    print('user exists so...')
    print('I can see this line, no problem. But not the next until enter is pressed')
    print('-=- Send file: (Y/N)')
    confirm = input('')
```

Or (as it just occurred to me) are you trying to accept the single character Y or N without the enter key being pressed?

Comment: No, the prompt does not show up until I press enter. So the Y would not be stored as confirm on the first enter press. I'd need to press it twice. It's the same problem as if the input was on send file. Either way, I see the last printed line, Must push enter, and then it is ready to accept input on the next press of the enter key.

Comment: So the program pauses, you press "Y" and enter.  THEN, you get the prompt, and have to press "Y" then enter, again?

Comment: Yes, that's why it feels really buggy. Any character that I type after the print statement does not get written to my input. Instead, the input only begins accepting values after I press enter one time after the print statements.

Comment: I think you need to create a minimal running program that demonstrates this.  It almost seems like you have another thread or process that is waiting for input from the keyboard that doesn't release it until it gets the enter press.

Comment: Do you think the solution might be in thread locking? I haven't been able to figure out when a good time to use it would be yet. It's never seemed to have an impact. You think this might be a case? If so which thread would you think? Send or receive?

Comment: I don't think thread locking would help (whatever that is).  The question here is:  Where is the first response and enter key that you are typing going?  It is not going to this piece of code, so it is going somewhere else.  But where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219275/discussion-between-j-krajewski-and-rufusvs).

Answer (score 0):

You could fake the enter press using the keyboard library. Just install it and import it. The actual code for faking it is just one line. I think keyboard.send("enter") should work just fine.

Comment: Interesting. So I assume there is a lower lever way to control it without installing the library?